# The strange behavior with the command variable | getline in awk

Tags: awk

Problem: the command variable value of `li12[q]` cannot be referenced as its own actual content.

Symptom: Once I truly reference the the command variable value of `li12[q]`, thus failed with fatal: expression for `|` redirection has null string value.

Notes:

1. But the command variable of `li12[q]` does have its own value, which is just same as the preceding `getline` variable of k5 does！
2. The corresponding syntax and structure should have no problem since the command variable name `li12[q]` itself can be referenced.

```
# 
# 
# lspci -v|grep -Ei "fib|scsi|raid|sas|net|ide|ata"|grep -i ^[0-9]|awk  '{kin1[NR]=$1; prt[NR]="";for(ik=2;ik<=NF;ik++){prt[NR]=prt[NR]$ik" "}}END\
{while("ls -l /sys/class|grep -Ei \"scsi|sas|fc|net|ide|ata\"|grep -Eiv \"disk|tape|device|gen\""|getline){li11[++h1]=$9}; for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)\
{for(s=1;s<=h1;s++){h2=0;d3="(find /sys/class/"li11[s]" -type l -exec bash -c '\''echo s `ls -l {}`'\'' \\;|grep -i devices|grep -Ei \""kin1[i]"(/|$)\")\
2>/dev/null"; while(d3|getline){k5=li12[++h2]=$10$11$12; k6=h2}; for(q=1;q<=h2;q++){if(li12[q] ~/[a-zA-Z]/){ while("echo -e \"li12[q]\""|getline k7); k2=k7; k3=$1;\
if( q == h2 ){s=h1+1}; if(q>1){kin1[i]=prt[i]=""};printf " %-16s%-6s%-16s%-16s%-100s%-16s\n",kin1[i],k6,k5,k3,prt[i],k2}}}}}'
 03:00.0         1     /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/device->../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.2/0000:03:00.0/host0s RAID bus controller: Hewlett-Packard Company Smart Array Gen8 Controllers (rev 01)                  li12[q]         
 04:00.0         1     /sys/class/net/eth0/device->../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:04:00.0s Ethernet controller: Emulex Corporation OneConnect 10Gb NIC (be3) (rev 01)                          li12[q]         
 04:00.1         1     /sys/class/net/eth1/device->../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:04:00.1s Ethernet controller: Emulex Corporation OneConnect 10Gb NIC (be3) (rev 01)                          li12[q]         
 04:00.2         1     /sys/class/iscsi_host/host3/device->../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:04:00.2/host3s Mass storage controller: Emulex Corporation OneConnect 10Gb iSCSI Initiator (be3) (rev 01)          li12[q]         
 04:00.3         1     /sys/class/iscsi_host/host4/device->../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:04:00.3/host4s Mass storage controller: Emulex Corporation OneConnect 10Gb iSCSI Initiator (be3) (rev 01)          li12[q]         
 05:00.0         1     /sys/class/fc_host/host1/device->../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:05:00.0/host1s Fibre Channel: QLogic Corp. ISP2532-based 8Gb Fibre Channel to PCI Express HBA (rev 02)             li12[q]         
 05:00.1         1     /sys/class/fc_host/host2/device->../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:05:00.1/host2s Fibre Channel: QLogic Corp. ISP2532-based 8Gb Fibre Channel to PCI Express HBA (rev 02)             li12[q]         
# 
# 
# 
# lspci -v|grep -Ei "fib|scsi|raid|sas|net|ide|ata"|grep -i ^[0-9]|awk  '{kin1[NR]=$1; prt[NR]="";for(ik=2;ik<=NF;ik++){prt[NR]=prt[NR]$ik" "}}END\         
{while("ls -l /sys/class|grep -Ei \"scsi|sas|fc|net|ide|ata\"|grep -Eiv \"disk|tape|device|gen\""|getline){li11[++h1]=$9}; for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)\
{for(s=1;s<=h1;s++){h2=0;d3="(find /sys/class/"li11[s]" -type l -exec bash -c '\''echo s `ls -l {}`'\'' \\;|grep -i devices|grep -Ei \""kin1[i]"(/|$)\")\
2>/dev/null"; while(d3|getline){k5=li12[++h2]=$10$11$12; k6=h2}; for(q=1;q<=h2;q++){if(li12[q] ~/[a-zA-Z]/){ while("echo -e "li12[q]""|getline k7); k2=k7; k3=$1; \
if( q == h2 ){s=h1+1}; if(q>1){kin1[i]=prt[i]=""};printf " %-16s%-6s%-16s%-16s%-100s%-16s\n",kin1[i],k6,k5,k3,prt[i],k2}}}}}'
awk: cmd. line:3: (FILENAME=- FNR=7) fatal: expression for `|' redirection has null string value
# 
#
```

---

EDIT here is the above code formatted vastly more legibly courtesy of @glennjackman:

```
lspci -v \
| grep -Ei "fib|scsi|raid|sas|net|ide|ata" \
| grep -i ^[0-9] \
| awk  '
    {
        kin1[NR] = $1
        prt[NR] = ""
        for (ik = 2; ik <= NF; ik++) {prt[NR] = prt[NR] $ik " "}
    }
    END {
        while ("ls -l /sys/class | grep -Ei \"scsi|sas|fc|net|ide|ata\" | grep -Eiv \"disk|tape|device|gen\"" | getline) {
            li11[++h1] = $9
        }
        for (i = 1; i <= NR;i++) {
            for (s = 1; s <= h1;s++) {
                h2 = 0
                d3 = "(find /sys/class/"li11[s]" -type l -exec bash -c '\''echo s `ls -l {}`'\'' \\; | grep -i devices | grep -Ei \""kin1[i]"(/|$)\") 2>/dev/null"
                while (d3 | getline){
                    k5 = li12[++h2] = $10 $11 $12
                    k6 = h2
                }
                for (q = 1; q <= h2;q++){
                    if (li12[q] ~/[a-zA-Z]/) {
                        while ("echo -e "li12[q]"" | getline k7)
                            k2 = k7
                        k3 = $1
                        if (q == h2) {s = h1+1}
                        if (q > 1) {kin1[i] = prt[i] = ""}
                        printf " %-16s%-6s%-16s%-16s%-100s%-16s\n", kin1[i], k6, k5, k3, prt[i], k2
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
'
```

Now there is a different failed result/progress with the above same awk script on the RHEL 6.4 system.
Notes: All the preivous failed results about the same null string value just run on the RHEL 5.8 systems.

```
sh: ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.2/0000:03:00.0/host0: No such file or directory
 03:00.0         1     /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/device->../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.2/0000:03:00.0/host0s               RAID bus controller: Hewlett-Packard Company Smart Array Gen8 Controllers (rev 01)                                  
sh: ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:04:00.0: No such file or directory
 04:00.0         1     /sys/class/net/eth0/device->../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:04:00.0s               Ethernet controller: Emulex Corporation OneConnect 10Gb NIC (be3) (rev 01)                                          
sh: ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:04:00.1: No such file or directory
 04:00.1         1     /sys/class/net/eth1/device->../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:04:00.1s               Ethernet controller: Emulex Corporation OneConnect 10Gb NIC (be3) (rev 01)                                          
sh: ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:04:00.2/host3: No such file or directory
 04:00.2         1     /sys/class/iscsi_host/host3/device->../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:04:00.2/host3s               Mass storage controller: Emulex Corporation OneConnect 10Gb iSCSI Initiator (be3) (rev 01)                          
sh: ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:04:00.3/host4: No such file or directory
 04:00.3         1     /sys/class/iscsi_host/host4/device->../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:04:00.3/host4s               Mass storage controller: Emulex Corporation OneConnect 10Gb iSCSI Initiator (be3) (rev 01)                          
sh: ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:05:00.0/host1: No such file or directory
 05:00.0         1     /sys/class/fc_host/host1/device->../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:05:00.0/host1s               Fibre Channel: QLogic Corp. ISP2532-based 8Gb Fibre Channel to PCI Express HBA (rev 02)                             
sh: ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:05:00.1/host2: No such file or directory
 05:00.1         1     /sys/class/fc_host/host2/device->../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:05:00.1/host2s               Fibre Channel: QLogic Corp. ISP2532-based 8Gb Fibre Channel to PCI Express HBA (rev 02)
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure that at least part of the problem is the trailing backslash characters

Comment: Your code is pretty much inpenetrable. For starters, please replace `lspci -v|grep -Ei "fib|scsi|raid|sas|net|ide|ata"|grep -i ^[0-9]` with a fixed set of strings that we can use to test your `awk` code. Next please rewrite your `awk` code so that it's readable. Use variable names that make sense (not just `d3`, `h2`, `s`, etc.). Explain what it's supposed to do and what transform(s) you're trying to achieve. Better still, remove everything from the code that's irrelevant to the issue you're trying to describe. Make the example as small and as self-contained as you possibly can.

Comment: Unfortunately, reading your code is extremely difficult due to the formatting and the choice of variable names.

Comment: @glennjackman introduced white space to your code (thanks Glenn!) which goes a long way toward making it legible, now come up with meaningful variable names to take it the next big step towards being understandable. It's hard to help you debug code with names like `d3`, `k6`, and `li12`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rowboat  Thank you very much for your great wonderful answer
I have already tested this answer, and also it has run successfully!

Just only replace with the following statement:
from:

```
while ("echo -e "li12[q]"" | getline k7)
```

to  :

```
while (("echo -e "li12[q]"") | getline k7)
```

Answer (score 4):

Whitespace is free, you should use some.

Is this what you're doing?

```bash
lspci -v \
| grep -Ei "fib|scsi|raid|sas|net|ide|ata" \
| grep -i ^[0-9] \
| awk  '
    {
        kin1[NR] = $1
        prt[NR] = ""
        for (ik = 2; ik <= NF; ik++) {prt[NR] = prt[NR] $ik " "}
    }
    END {
        while ("ls -l /sys/class | grep -Ei \"scsi|sas|fc|net|ide|ata\" | grep -Eiv \"disk|tape|device|gen\"" | getline) {
            li11[++h1] = $9
        }
        for (i = 1; i <= NR;i++) {
            for (s = 1; s <= h1;s++) {
                h2 = 0
                d3 = "(find /sys/class/"li11[s]" -type l -exec bash -c '\''echo s `ls -l {}`'\'' \\; | grep -i devices | grep -Ei \""kin1[i]"(/|$)\") 2>/dev/null"
                while (d3 | getline){
                    k5 = li12[++h2] = $10 $11 $12
                    k6 = h2
                }
                for (q = 1; q <= h2;q++){
                    if (li12[q] ~/[a-zA-Z]/) {
                        while ("echo -e "li12[q]"" | getline k7)
                            k2 = k7
                        k3 = $1
                        if (q == h2) {s = h1+1}
                        if (q > 1) {kin1[i] = prt[i] = ""}
                        printf " %-16s%-6s%-16s%-16s%-100s%-16s\n", kin1[i], k6, k5, k3, prt[i], k2
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
'
```

Comment: Yes.   thank you for your great effort ！

Comment: If you use this, are you still getting the error?

Comment: Yes,   just the same failure result.

Comment: What line does the error message indicate?

Comment: I copied this version of the code into the question so we can continue discussions about the problem there.

Comment: almost just the same error return:                                                                                awk: cmd. line:13: (FILENAME=- FNR=7) fatal: expression for `|' redirection has null string value

Comment: The pipe of getline must be within the while () statement ....